Eclipse Git, Checkout Remote Branch as new Local Branch
When changing the branch in Eclipse with Team > Switch To > Other ...
it shows Remote Tracking, there I select the branch I want to checkout.
Usually this resulted in checking the branch out as new local branch, where I can commit changes directly too and merge other branches into that branch.
However, the branch somehow gets checked out as a non local branch, where I cant commit to it and cant merge other branches into it.
How to change it back to the old behaviour, where a remote branch is automatically checked out as new local branch?

In Git, if you aren't on a branch, them you are in detached mode. You can confirm this from a command line by typing git status. However, even in detached mode you can still create new commits and do merges. I can't think of a reason why Eclipse would block those operations while detached, so my gut feeling is maybe something else is going on that is blocking the UI, like maybe you're in the middle of a merge or some other operation? (git status can help you confirm that too.)

@TTT This is not a question about the command line Git which might be not even available here.

In the Branches dialog (which will be shown on Team > Switch To > Other ...), when I select a branch below Remote Tracking and click Check Out, I will be asked and I can choose Check out as New Local Branch (which is what you want), Check out Commit (which you might chosen by mistake) or_Cancel_.

@howlger thanks I dont have the extra dialog "Check out as New Local Branch" for whatever reason. However I found a workaround by selecting "New Branch ..." where it automatically selects the one chosen from Remote Tracking.

@howlger Good to know that it's completely self contained and there may not be a command line Git available on the system.  Regarding OP's scenario, does eclipse block you from committing and merging while detached?

@TTT No. When you check out a remote branch, you will be asked whether to Check out as New Local Branch (which is what you mostly want) or Check out Commit. This dialog is shown by default, but can be suppressed (not recommended, but this is what happened here). Without this dialog it is less intuitive (like the Git command line): different commands to reach the same goal (local branch with a specific remote branch as upstream) depending whether you select a local or a remote branch.

@TTT Same problem on the Git command line, but without an intuitive solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/6505250 (11696 votes!).

@howlger I agree when having multiple remotes, checking out a copy of a remote branch is not intuitive from the command line. I would say it's probably more likely to accidentally go detached from the command line than with a UI that can prompt for it. I think this question and answer explain how to help prevent from going detached, however, I'm more curious about this part of the question, "However, the branch somehow gets checked out as a non local branch, where I cant commit to it and cant merge other branches into it." I don't understand why OP can't commit or merge while detached.

@TTT You need to create a local branch first to be able to commit or merge, don't you?

@howlger Not at all. Branches are just named pointers to a commit ID. You can work entirely detached if you wish, and point a branch to a commit later. I purposely detach and delete my current branch whenever I finish a feature to indicate to myself later when I come back that I don't have anything I need to save and am ready to start fresh. When I come back, sometimes I just start coding while still detached. I also test merges while detached so I don't have the added overhead of creating and deleting a temporary branch before and after the test. That being said, I doubt many people do this.

@TTT Thanks, I see. You can do this also in Eclipse, but when checking out a commit you get by default the following "Detached HEAD" warning which can be suppressed: "You are in the 'detached HEAD' state. This means that you don't have a local branch checked out. You can look around, but it's not recommended to commit changes. The reason is that these commits would not be on any branch and would not be visible after checking out another branch. If you want to make changes, create or check out a local branch first." You can not push a detach HEAD, right?

@howlger you can "sort of" push a detached head. You don't actually need a local branch, but you do need a remote ref to push. See this question and answer for details, particularly the side note.

Selecting "Detached HEAD and checkout of remote-tracking branch" resolves the issue and I can checkout the remote branch as new local branch.

