# How to move multiple committed, but unpushed commits to a newly created branch, keeping all commit information

Tags: git

**Context**

I have a repository with hundreds of committed and pushed commits.
Now I have 10 committed but not yet pushed commit on my local git repository, I would like to create a new branch locally, and move all the 10 commits to that branch, doing all this locally. Then when I will be online next time I would like to sync my remote with that exact state.  (As far as I see this case is not the same as [moving committed (but not pushed) changes to a new branch after pull](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5066041/1157814) because that is only one single commit)

**Question**

Is this possible at all? If yes what is the most efficient way?
(please be aware I am not a git guru)

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as creating a new branch at the top commit.

```
git checkout -b your_new_branch_name
```

Now you are on the new branch at the same commit. If you like, you can reset your old branch (possibly master or main) to the upstream after that.

```
# after creating a new branch reset your master or main
# assuming current branch is master (or main)
git reset --hard origin/master (or main)
```

When you want to push your changes on this new branch, you can either merge master to your new branch (possibly after rebasing on master) and push, or create a pull request from new branch to upstream master.

Answer (score 0):

There are very practical solutions for your problem.
There is no need to write it all here so check the following links:

[Git create branch from range of previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853681/git-create-branch-from-range-of-previous-commits/9853814#9853814)

[How to copy commits from one branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474353/how-to-copy-commits-from-one-branch-to-another)

[How to cherry-pick a range of commits and merge them into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-them-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491)

They worked for me, and sure, will work for you.