# How to discard a specific file changes from git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I want to be able to apply a stash that looks like this:

```
git stash show --stat stash@\{1\} 
 extensions/99/fill-thresholds.json            |  2 +-
 html/js/1.js                           | 10 ++++++++++
 html/pages/su/2.html            |  4 ++--
 html/pages/su/popups/3.html | 21 +++++++++++----------
 sql/2 - data/4.sql              |  6 +++---
 sql/3 - keys/5.sql               |  4 ++--
 sql/5 - views/6.sql          |  2 +-
 7 files changed, 30 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)
```

When I try to apply that stash I get a conflict error:

```
git stash apply stash@\{1\} 
Auto-merging sql/2 - data/4.sql
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sql/2 - data/4.sql
```

And then I have tried to resolved the conflict but then my other files were not applied, if I run the apply that stash again I get that conflict error again.

I don't really care about the file with the error so I was thinking if there's a way to discard that file only from the stash so when I try to apply it I don't get that error or how can I continue applying the stash after I resolved the conflict?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "my other files were not applied"? That's impossible: the stash is not applied on a file-by-file basis; instead, all changes are applied at once, just application of some of them may result in conflicts. So I'd inspect what `git status` tells you after `git stash apply` more closely.  May be you just forgot to commit?

Comment: By the way, discarding a conflict in such a case is simple: use `git checkout --ours "sql/2 - data/4.sql"` and then `git add` it to the index. `--ours` means our local version (the one at the HEAD`), and `--theirs` means the version in the stash.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a way to modify a stash, but I would just pop the stash in a new branch that doesn't have any conflicts, remove the files that you don't care about, and then stash/reapply on your branch of interest.

Comment: Thank you @Jin, or is there any other command to run after I resolved the conflict so I can continue with the stash apply?

Comment: BTW, you can create a branch from a stash via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925099/git-stash-changes-apply-to-new-branch. See answer by Rodney Golpe.

Comment: Ok I have the files in the other branch, how can I pass those files to the original branch without stashing again in this temporary branch and transfering them again?

Comment: Hmm, yeah my idea was to just `git stash`, `git checkout other_branch`, `git stash pop`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can merge directly from a stash "git merge stash@{XX}' and use the rerere mechanism to handle your repeated merge conflicts, see https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html