# Are `git stash save` and `git stash` the same?

Tags: git

I am reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/6925136/156458 for learning `git stash`.

I was wondering if `git stash save` in the first method and `git stash` in the second are the same? What difference does `save` make?

Comment: My curiosity extended to Google, which brought me here. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick quote from the [documentation of `git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the `HEAD` commit.
>
> The modifications stashed away by this command can be listed with `git stash list`, inspected with `git stash show`, and restored (potentially on top of a different commit) with `git stash apply`. Calling `git stash` without any arguments is equivalent to `git stash save`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are the same.

With `git stash save` you can provide an optional message that will be used for the stash, so it can be found more easily in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Now, `git stash save` has been **deprecated**, and now we should use `git stash push`.

- `git stash push` will stash tracked files
- `git stash push -u` will stash untracked files
- `git stash push -a` will stash ignored files

More information is **[here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash)**