# Move uncommitted changes from current branch to another branch that conflicts with those changes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-stash

Suppose I am on branch `master` and I start making some changes.

I make the changes to a file which is already opened in Emacs (so under the hood, as checkouts happen, Emacs is unaware unless I revert-buffer constantly).

The file did exist in branch `other_branch` which was intended to be merged into `master` later on. But the file did not exist in `master` until I accidentally saved it from Emacs.

The changes are uncommitted, but I realize that I shouldn't have been making the changes on `master` and had intended to checkout a different branch before starting on the changes.

I don't want to lose the current work, but also don't want to commit it to `master`.

I have tried using `git stash` followed by `git checkout other_branch` but this gives me an error saying that, because of the uncommitted changes, I am not allowed to switch branches to `other_branch`:

```
ems@computer:~$ git checkout other_branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    some_file
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

The files that I began (accidentally) modifying in `master` did already exist in `other_branch`, so just checking out `other_branch` would destroy my working directory copy, with the changes, correct?

I tried `stash`, which did seem to stash the changes, but then I got the error message above when I tried to checkout.

**Summary**

1. checkout some new branch, `other_branch` tracking `master`.
2. create a new file `test.txt` in `other_branch` and open it for editing in Emacs. Commit to `other_branch`.
3. back in the terminal, checkout master.
4. Back in Emacs, you forget you're now on master, start making some changes to `test.txt` and save the file. It's a totally new file as far as `master` is concerned.

How do you get those changes over into `other_branch`?

Comment: What gives a `git status` right after your `git stash`? The all point of `git stash` is to clean the working tree, which should then allow any checkout you want.

Comment: `stash` doesn't appear to do anything to untracked files -- such as the one not committed. It looks like the problem is that the file (which was opened in emacs during a checkout) did *not* exist in `master`

Comment: so, relative to `master` this is a new file, not a part of what gets stashed.

Answer (score 0):

If the untracked files are an issue during the checkout, maybe you can try:

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

From the [`git stash` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> If the `--include-untracked` option is used, all untracked files are also stashed and then cleaned up with `git clean`, leaving the working directory in a very clean state

---

Since that doesn't work either (on the stash pop), you could imply:

- Make the commmit (in master branch)
- checkout develop and cherry-pick that commmit
- checkout to master and reset it to `HEAD~`

Comment: I get a message that just says `could not restore untracked files from stash` after I checkout and try to `stash apply` or `stash pop`.

Comment: I think the problem is that it is untracked as far as master is concerned, but already tracked in the branch where I try to `stash pop`.

Comment: @EMS maybe you don't need stash then. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @EMS try `git checkout stash@{0} -- test.txt` after creating the stash

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily rename the file ?

```
$ mv test.txt test.txt.tmp
$ git checkout other_branch
$ mv test.txt.tmp test.txt
```

Inspect changes & commit

Comment: Sure, but I want to do it the right way. This goes outside of version control to perform a version control task. In a pinch I would do this. But I am asking here to learn what the actual `git` provisions are for doing this.

Comment: You can go with @VonC's stash, or create a commit on a new branch and merge. The thing is : your first version of `test.txt` is *already* versioned. Doing the `mv back; checkout; mv forth` trick is merely replaying the editing of the file - you would be in the same state if you had been on `other_branch` from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following:

From `master` do `git add` for the untracked, conflicting file. Now that it is tracked, do `git stash` and checkout `other_branch`. Now, `git stash pop` will attempt to merge the tracked-in-stash version with the tracked-in-`other_branch` version. This probably will create a merge conflict, so you have to open the file(s) and resolve any conflicts, and be sure to `git add` and `commit` them on `other_branch`. Then go back to `master` and just verify that the files are not staged for commit and are not present in that branch.

This allows them to be treated as if they were tracked within the stash, but without needing to actually commit and merge from master.