# git - commit modified files from one branch to another branch

Tags: git

Scenario:
I have 2 branches: `dev` and `sprint1`

1. I made some changes while checked out to branch `sprint1`;
2. I don't want to add/commit these changes in `sprint1`, I want to add/commit them on `dev`;
3. I tried to checkout `dev` without committing changes in `sprint1` first, but the checkout fails;

My question is: How can I bring those changes in `sprint1` to `dev` without committing them to `sprint1` ;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge my local uncommitted changes into another Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556923/how-to-merge-my-local-uncommitted-changes-into-another-git-branch)

Answer (score 4):

You can merge your local modifications into the branch you want to checkout.

On your `sprint1` branch do:

```
git checkout --merge dev
```

This will merge the local modifications of the working directory into the `dev` branch and switch to it. The changes are just merged and not committed. So you can now go on as usual.

```
git add ....
git commit
```

From the [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) documentation

> **--merge**
>
> When switching branches, if you have local modifications to one or more files that are different between the current branch and the branch to which you are switching, the command refuses to switch branches in order to preserve your modifications in context. **However, with this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch.**

Answer (score 3):

### [Stashing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing)

```
git stash
git checkout dev
git stash apply
git commit
```