# How do I merge my stash into another branch?

Tags: git

I have a stash (WIP on master a6c392c) that I would like to merger into another branch called Develop1.  Develop1 is several commits behind if it matters.  I do not want these changes on the master branch.

Comment: Should be as easy as stashing your changes, moving to the branch, and unstashing your changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge my local uncommitted changes into another Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556923/how-to-merge-my-local-uncommitted-changes-into-another-git-branch)

Comment: Note that most (all?) answers to questions about applying the stashed changes to a state of the repository different from that the stash was recorded at actually tell about *applying* the stash entry, not *merging* it -- presupposing that's what the questioneer actually *meant.* If, instead, you did really mean merging then `git stash` supports the `branch` subcommand which allows to create a proper local branch out of a stash entry; this branch can then be freely merged with `git merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the branch you want, then apply the stash:

```
$ git checkout -b Develop1

$ git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

For a clean working tree:

```
git checkout Develop1
git stash pop
git add -A
git commit
git checkout master
```

For a working tree with uncommitted changes:

```
git stash -u
git checkout Develop1
git stash pop stash@{1}
git add -A
git commit
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just change to that branch and then do `git stash pop`? You might have some conflicts to resolve, which is kind of awkward with stashes.

Personally, I typically avoid using stashs and make temporary commits that I can rebase or cherry pick, and remove or squash when I'm done with them.